# when I insert an iframe in office365 "sharepoint online" it gives me an error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
I found this reason : The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself .
anyone know how to bypass this error?

Comment: I put the link of 365 office outlook in a web part to view the outlook owa directly in sharepoint with version 2007/2010 displays but no 365

Comment: can you explain yourself better? I can't understand your english..what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint gives you an error because is not allowing the render of contents that cames from outside sources, that's because it is setting the X-Frame optin to "SAMEORIGIN" that's mean that it can render only websites whitin sharepoint itself, try to have a look at this, I didn't test it yet, but you can start to give it a go. Let me know. 
[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/is-there-a-way-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-or-at-least-modify-it](http://Sharepoint%20give%20you%20an%20error%20because%20is%20not%20allowing%20the%20render%20of%20contents%20that%20cames%20from%20outside%20sources,%20that's%20because%20it%20is%20setting%20the%20X-Frame%20optin%20to%20%22SAMEORIGIN%22%20that's%20mean%20that%20it%20can%20render%20only%20websites%20whitin%20sharepoint%20itself,%20try%20to%20have%20a%20look%20at%20this,%20I%20didn't%20test%20it%20yet,%20but%20you%20can%20start%20to%20give%20it%20a%20go.%20Let%20me%20know.%20https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/is-there-a-way-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-or-at-least-modify-it)